# HighCharts populate Pie Chart with data from SQL Database

Tags: c#, highcharts

I'm new to web design and am trying to populate a highcharts pie chart with data from SQL Database using C#.  I have done it sucessfully for a Bar Chart but am having trouble with a pie chart.  Basically i have a table tblReport1 that contains 2 fields CustomerType and TotalOrders

I can get it to bring in the values but i can't get my slices to rename to the data in CustomerType field.  I have tried a couple of suggestions on this forum but can't get them to work.  Below is my code any suggestions would be grateful.

```
private void Report1()
{
    dsSeries = BindData();

    if (dsSeries == null) return;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        hidXCategories11.Add(dr["CustomerType"]);
    }

    foreach (DataRow dr1 in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        hidValues11.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr1["TotalOrders"]));
        yValues = hidValues11.ToArray(typeof(object)) as object[];
    }


    DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
    .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
    .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Orders by Customer Type" })
    .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' Orders'; }" })
    .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
    {
        Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
        {
            ShowInLegend = true,
            AllowPointSelect = true,
            DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
            {
                Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y; }"
            }
        }
    })

    .SetSeries(new[]
       {
               new Series { Type = ChartTypes.Pie, Name = "help!", Data = new Data(yValues) }
       });



    ltrChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();

}
```

Comment: Can you put up what the javscript that is sent to the client looks like? This is .NET code (I didn't even knwo there was a .NET interface) but the "real" highcharts code all runs clientside. At a glance you look like you are setting the right options but it will be easier to check if we can see the real options in the javascript.

Comment: Hi Chris I have no javascript just a section in my aspx document  <asp:Literal ID="ltrChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal> and i link to the highchart.js file

Comment: @bsmith, can you look at your "live" page at that location where you literal tag should be and then tell us what that javascript is? The .NET highcharts API creates a literal tag that it writes to (it actually just creates a string of javascript and puts it in the literal tag - more or less).

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: { renderTo:'chart_container', plotShadow: false }, 
  plotOptions: { pie: { allowPointSelect: true, dataLabels: { formatter: function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y; } } } }, 
  title: { text: 'Orders by Customer Type' }, 
  tooltip: { formatter: function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y; } }, 
  series: [{ data: [50, 20, 5], name: 'help!!', type: 'pie' }]
 });
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/ the format for the pie chart data is two parts, the label and the data item.

In yours it looks like the series data is just a single array of integers.

So I think you'll need to change your `Series` object to accept a different format of data.

Sadly the examples in the Highcharts.Net documentation are a little lacking and don't seem to have examples of this so you might have to look at what the intellisense has to offer.

The bottom line though is that your pie wedges need to be named in the data series, not as categories or anything else.

**Edit for some sample code**

I was looking at their site and they have a help forum there with the following sample code amongst it

```
       series.Add(new Serie
        {
            data = new object[] { 
                new object[] { "Firefox", 45 }, 
                new object[] { "IE", 24.8 }, 
                new object[] { "Chrome", 12.8 },
                new object[] { "Safari", 8.5 }, 
                new object[] { "Opera", 5.2 }, 
                new object[] { "Outros", 3.7 } 
            }
        });
```

Source: http://highcharts.codeplex.com/discussions/269347

I can't test this but from the context of the post it looks like it should do the job.

Comment: For the data values i use data type Object to store the values do you know what i need to use for the slice name.  I have tried an array list and string but neither work

Comment: @bsmith : can you post some working code..as you accepted this as answer